# Why Browser does not reflect changes made in JSP page or Angular Controller?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, eclipse, jsp

I am working on **Spring MVC** framework with Eclipse and **Angular JS** for FrontEnd Data Binding, I use **Tomcat Server** for Running the Project.

Project is running Properly, but when i open any JSP or JavaScript file to make changes and made the Changes then i refresh the browser the changes are not getting reflected on browser

I opened the file with Eclipse Default Editor as well as Sublime Text

Sometimes changes are getting reflected only after clearing browser cache, and sometimes after restarting tomcat server.
Sometimes i do both of these.

I have also tried chrome cache killer plugin and chrome dev tools -> disable cache and incognito window

Sometimes situation comes like even after restarting server and clearing browser cache code changes not reflecting on browser.

It makes development process much slower.
please suggest something which can solve this issue and can make development faster.

Comment: I think you should re-deploy your application every time you make a change, im working with Thymeleaf (similar to JSP) and i have the same problem, but we solved it using Jrebel to refresh our build while it's running and avoid the redeploy. Also sometime we must clean the cache while the page is reloading. on chrome just right click above the refresh icon and you'll see the options to flush your cache

Answer (score 1):

When i changed the code in file which is opened in Sublime Text then its not reflecting in browser

After changing the file i have refreshed the eclipse project and cleaned browser cache and it started working.

I am not 100% sure but its working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the application every time and then Ctrl+f5 to do a hard refresh.